# Why are portraits of David Crockett and Sam Houston on the wall in Naked Gun?

Tags: production, props, naked-gun-final-insult

On the wall of Inspector Drebbin's home in *The Naked Gun 33 1/3: The Final Insult* are portraits of David Crockett and (probably) Sam Houston, both adopted Texans. Why? The writers and directors are from Wisconsin.

Answer (score 14):

**Probably because [David Zucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Zucker_(filmmaker)), the film's screenwriter and producer, is a huge [Alamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Alamo) buff**, the battle in which Crockett died and during which Houston was Commander in Chief in Texas. [Says Zucker himself](https://truewestmagazine.com/david-zucker-writer-director-a-producer/):

> **In all of my movies you will see a reference to Davy Crockett. His picture hangs on the wall of most of my movies**, but that’s just a coincidence having to do with my bringing the picture to the set and having the grips hang it prominently on a wall.

In fact, it's been Zucker's lifelong dream to make a Crockett bio pic. You can read more about it in this [LA Times article](http://articles.latimes.com/1991-11-17/entertainment/ca-496_1_davy-crockett) and about his desire for a world class Alamo museum in this [My SA article](http://www.mysanantonio.com/opinion/editorials/article/Build-an-Alamo-with-a-there-there-6279328.php). Zucker also [cameoed **as** Crockett in *Naked Gun 2 1/2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102510/combined). That's him firing a musket around 0:35 here:

Comment: I'd love to see a good Crokett biopic. Although some may be disappointed if it doesn't show him killing him a bar when he was only three.